# Pandas solution to computing the maximum of two sums of two columns?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a DataFrame with (amongst others) four colours with numerical values. I want to add a column to the DataFrame that has the maximum of the two sums obtained from summing two columns.

My solutions so far is

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame(data={'text': ['a','b','c'], 'a':[1,2,3],'b':[2,3,4],'c':[5,4,2],'d':[-2,4,1]})
df['sum1'] = df['a'].add(df['b'])
df['sum2'] = df['c'].add(df['d'])

df['maxsum'] = df[['sum1','sum2']].max(axis=1)
```

which gives the desired result.

I am pretty sure, there is a more concise way to do this...

Comment: your approach is not bad. Why do you need a more "concise" way?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your approach. In fact, it is the approach I would take if nothing more than the fact it is easy to read and figure out what you are doing. But if you are looking for another solution, here is one using [numpy.ufunc.reduceat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'text': ['a','b','c'], 'a':[1,2,3],'b':[2,3,4],'c':[5,4,2],'d':[-2,4,1]})
# we skip the first column and convert to an array - df[df.columns[1:]].values
# we specify the indicies to slice - np.arange(len(df.columns[1:]))[::2]
# then find the max
df['max'] = np.max(np.add.reduceat(df[df.columns[1:]].values,
                                   np.arange(len(df.columns[1:]))[::2],
                                   axis=1),
                   axis=1)

  text  a  b  c  d  max
0    a  1  2  5 -2    3
1    b  2  3  4  4    8
2    c  3  4  2  1    7
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that it much more concised, but instead of your current approach you can apply *one-shot* assignment:

```
df = df.assign(sum1=df[['a', 'b']].sum(1), sum2=df[['c', 'd']].sum(1),
               maxsum=lambda df: df[['sum1','sum2']].max(1))
```

---

```
  text  a  b  c  d  sum1  sum2  maxsum
0    a  1  2  5 -2     3     3       3
1    b  2  3  4  4     5     8       8
2    c  3  4  2  1     7     3       7
```